# How to remove faint grey line above ComboBox and DatePicker JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx

I am in school for Java so please be gentle. 
I am working with JavaFX for my final and I am formatting the css, while testing the code I noticed this very faint grey bar above all my fields.  I did some Googling, found a solution, implemented it, but it only works for my textFields, not my ComboBox's or my DatePicker.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRTqt.png)

**CSS** my CSS works perfectly the way I want it to EXCEPT for that little grey top border.  Does anyone have any suggestions I could use to remove the dumb thing?

```
#datePicker {
    .date-picker {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
    -fx-border-style: hidden hidden solid hidden;
    -fx-border-color:  #919294;
    -fx-border-width: 2px;
}

#datePicker .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

#datePicker:focused .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, white, transparent, white;
}

#datePicker:focused {
    -fx-highlight-fill: #7ecfff;
}

#datePicker .content {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-text-fill: gray;
    -fx-highlight-fill: #7ecfff;
}   

#datePicker .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

}

**My DatePicker**

```
<DatePicker id="datePicker" fx:id="startDate" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="87.0" promptText="Start Date" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="206.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="80.0" />
<DatePicker id="datePicker" fx:id="endDate" layoutY="138.0" promptText="End Date" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="206.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="135.0" />
```

Comment: Without seeing the markup, I would guess you need to set the outline attribute to '0' for those form elements. If that doesn't work, please post your markup.

Comment: Do you set the outline attribute to 0 in the CSS? Do you know the selector? Is it the -fx-outer-border?

Comment: Never mind. That's just for the focus state.